# Clarification to: A finite group that has at most one subgroup of any size is cyclic

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have been reading:  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/coset.pdf

**Theorem 7.11 states: A finite group that has at most one subgroup of any size is cyclic.**

I think this is a very crude formulation of theorem stated in this thread: [If an Abelian group $G$ has order $n$ and at most one subgroup of order $d$ for all $d$ dividing $n$ then $G$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93515/if-an-abelian-group-g-has-order-n-and-at-most-one-subgroup-of-order-d-for)

I believe the author of Theorem 7.11. forgot to explicitly state the order of each subgroup H has to the order of group G. Also, I don't really see, if the groups really have to be abelian or not, example (?)

As always: Any constructive hint, comment, answer or recommendation for further reading are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps prove the contrapositive.

Comment: By missing out the conditions that the group is Abelian and that the order of the subgroup divides the order of the group, Theorem 7.11 is more general than the other statement because there is less you have to check before you can apply it. Of course it is easy that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group, and of course once you know a group is cyclic, you know that it (and all its subgroups) are abelian. But in the 7.11 formulation these are consequences not assumptions.

Comment: Relevant: [Groups having at most one subgroup of any given finite index](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/groups-having-at-most-one-subgroup-of-any-given-finite-index)

Answer (score 1):

You  are correct, it should explicitly state any size that divides the order of $G$. However the statement is still true in general. Here is the sketch of proof.
Since every subgroup of $G$ also has the same property, you may assume by induction that all subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Also it is clear that all subgroups are normal in $G$. Since all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are normal we deduce that $G$ is nilpotent. Hence $G$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups which are all cyclic. So $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: The group $\mathbb Z / 6\mathbb Z$ has exactly one subgroup for each divisor of $6$, but isn't a $p$-group. I think the condition that each subgroup is normal implies nilpotency, but not that it must be a $p$-group.

Comment: @Stefan I meant without loss of generality we may assume that $G$ is a $p$-group. I edited my answer in a,I hope, more clear way.

Comment: Yes, I like your proof as it is way simpler than the counting arguments from the link.